# Grouping With Pagination

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, oracle10g

This is my updated code.

```
<cfquery datasource="#dsn#" name="list">
    SELECT film_Director
    FROM main_Films
    WHERE film_Active = '1'
    GROUP BY film_Director
</cfquery>

<cfset OnEachPage=15>

<cfparam name="StartRow" default="1">
<cfset EndRow=StartRow + OnEachPage - 1>
<cfif EndRow GTE list.RecordCount>
    <cfset EndRow=list.RecordCount>
    <cfset Next=false>
<cfelse>
    <cfset Next=true>
    <cfif EndRow + OnEachPage GT list.RecordCount>
        <cfset NextNum=list.RecordCount - EndRow>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset NextNum= OnEachPage>
    </cfif>
    <cfset NextStart=EndRow + 1>
</cfif>
<cfif StartRow IS 1>
    <cfset Previous=false>
<cfelse>
    <cfset Previous=true>
    <cfset PreviousStart=StartRow - OnEachPage>
</cfif>

<cfset NumPages=Ceiling(list.RecordCount / OnEachPage)>
<cfparam name="PageNum" default="1">

<cfoutput><br>
    <center>Display Page #StartRow# to #EndRow# dari #list.RecordCount# Search.</center><p>
</cfoutput>
<table border="0">
    <tr align="center">
        <td valign="top">
            <cfif Previous>
                <cfoutput>
                <a href="filmby_Director.cfm?StartRow=#PreviousStart#& PageNum=#DecrementValue(PageNum)#<cfif IsDefined("Keyword")>&Keyword=#URLEncodedFormat(Keyword)#</cfif>">&lt;&lt;&nbsp;Page Before</a>
                </cfoutput>
            <cfelse>&nbsp;
            </cfif>
        </td>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#NumPages#" index="ThisPage">
            <cfoutput>
            <cfif ThisPage IS PageNum>
                <td>#ThisPage#</td>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset PageNumStart=(((ThisPage - 1) * OnEachPage) + 1)>
                <td><a href="filmby_Director.cfm?StartRow=#PageNumStart#&PageNum=#ThisPage#<cfif IsDefined("Keyword")>&Keyword=#URLEncodedFormat(Keyword)#</cfif>">#ThisPage#</a></td>
            </cfif>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfloop>
        <td valign="top">
            <cfif Next>
                <cfoutput>
                <i><a href="filmby_Director.cfm?StartRow=#NextStart#&   PageNum=#IncrementValue(PageNum)#<cfif IsDefined("Keyword")>&Keyword=#URLEncodedFormat(Keyword)#</cfif>">Next Page&nbsp;&gt;&gt;</a></i>
                  </cfoutput>
            <cfelse>
            </cfif>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" colspan="<cfoutput>#Evaluate(NumPages + 2)#</cfoutput>">
    <tr><tr>
    <table border="1" >
        <thead>
        <cfoutput>
            <tr><th colspan="4">#list.film_Director#</th></th></tr>
        </cfoutput>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th><th>Film Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Edit Description</th>
        </thead>
        <cfoutput query="list" startrow="#startrow#" maxrows="#OnEachPage#">
            <tbody>
                <tr align="left">
                    <td>#director_ID#</td>
                    <td>#film_Name#</td>
                    <td>#film_Desc#</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="editDesc" onBlur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </tbody>
        </cfoutput>
    </table>
```

I want to make a query with a pagination (next/before page) grouped by film directors.

Example of data: **Director A**/ABC Film, **Director B**/ASD Film, **Director A**/FDE Film, **Director A**/123 Film.

Then, I have problem to paginate the page. Can someone help me?
How can i group the data, and make next page.

Comment: Can you provide details about what you have tried?

Comment: hi @ScottStroz. i have updated my full unsuccessful code. tq.

Comment: your HTML is an utter mess, I'd start fixing that before doing anything around pagination, e.g. what's with things like `</tbody></tbody>` and `<tr><tr>` ?

Comment: @duncan im thinking to display the list of film in a table.

Comment: @shasha, clearly, but your HTML is completely invalid, also things like `</th></th>`, missing `</tr>`, you don't want to put `<tbody>` inside your `<cfoutput query>` loop as there should only be one of these tags in a table, not one for every row, etc etc

Comment: i dont think youre tryin to help me here @duncan

Answer (score 0):

Wich version of Oracle are you using? If 12c then you can use the new pagination feature:

```
select owner, object_name, object_id
from all_objects
order by owner, object_name
OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: im using 10g. is it applicable?

Answer (score -1):

This link would help you in getting your answer with understanding

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17asktom-093877.html

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY film_Director ASC) rownumber,
    film_Director
    FROM main_Films
    WHERE film_Active = '1'
    GROUP BY film_Director    
) as q1
WHERE q1.rownumber 
BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

It is not Tested yet, some tweaking might be required.

Comment: is it possible for me to do something like i have updated in my post?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This article is a follow up on the article you provided using Oracle 12c features : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-sep/o53asktom-1999186.html

Comment: @JanDoggen thanks for the response. i've tried the codes but still it do not reach my target.

Comment: @shasha: Provided the query in answer. you need to calculate the "start row" and "end row (start row + pageLimit)" for between clause. If this still not reach your target, please mention clearly what is your target.

Comment: @user1412508 i have updated my full code. but i am unable to display them well. am i missin anythin?

Comment: @Robert Merkwürdigeliebe thanks rob. it's a new knowledge. but its not applicable with 10g oracle :)

Comment: @user1412508 can you look at my latest question?

Comment: @Loki i need favour in my latest question.